# Lumen(Centurylink) Quantum Fiber on SRX320 with DHCP over IPoE

Tags: juniper, fiber, gpon

Been trying to configure Lumen's(Centurylink) Quantum Fiber service to work on a Juniper SRX320 using DHCP with IPoE.

Haven't been able to successfully pull a DHCP IP address yet.

Here's the configuration I've left off at, but I've tried quite a few variant configs, with no luck;

```
vlan-tagging;
speed 1g;
gigether-options {
    no-auto-negotiation;
}
unit 201 {
    description "Quantum(centurylink) GPON fiber WAN.";
    encapsulation dix;
    vlan-id 201;
    family inet {
        dhcp {
            force-discover;
        }
    }
}
```

The gigether-options/no-auto-negotiation has been the only way I can get the link to come up, but that may just be a 'false link', as I'm forcing it up with this config.(My understanding my be incorrect, but I think that's the case.)

Here are my current interface metrics/statistics with the above configuration;

```
Physical interface: ge-0/0/7, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Interface index: 146, SNMP ifIndex: 522
  Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1518, LAN-PHY mode, Link-mode: Full-duplex, Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None,
  Loop Detect PDU Error: None, Ethernet-Switching Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled, Source filtering: Disabled,
  Flow control: Disabled, Auto-negotiation: Disabled, Remote fault: Online
  Device flags   : Present Running
  Interface flags: SNMP-Traps Internal: 0x0
  CoS queues     : 8 supported, 8 maximum usable queues
  Current address: 64:c3:d6:c0:a0:07, Hardware address: 64:c3:d6:c0:a0:07
  Last flapped   : 2023-10-06 15:00:41 MDT (18:00:06 ago)
  Input rate     : 0 bps (0 pps)
  Output rate    : 0 bps (0 pps)
  Active alarms  : None
  Active defects : None
  PCS statistics                      Seconds
    Bit errors                             0
    Errored blocks                         0
  Ethernet FEC statistics              Errors
    FEC Corrected Errors                    0
    FEC Uncorrected Errors                  0
    FEC Corrected Errors Rate               0
    FEC Uncorrected Errors Rate             0
  Interface transmit statistics: Disabled

  Logical interface ge-0/0/7.201 (Index 84) (SNMP ifIndex 534)
    Description: Quantum(centurylink) GPON fiber WAN.
    Flags: Up SNMP-Traps 0x0 VLAN-Tag [ 0x8100.201 ]  Encapsulation: ENET2
    Input packets : 0
    Output packets: 2
    Security: Zone: Internet
    Allowed host-inbound traffic : ping
    Protocol inet, MTU: 1500
    Max nh cache: 100000, New hold nh limit: 100000, Curr nh cnt: 0, Curr new hold cnt: 0, NH drop cnt: 0
      Flags: Sendbcast-pkt-to-re

  Logical interface ge-0/0/7.32767 (Index 85) (SNMP ifIndex 515)
    Flags: Up SNMP-Traps 0x0 VLAN-Tag [ 0x0000.0 ]  Encapsulation: ENET2
    Input packets : 0
    Output packets: 0
    Security: Zone: Null
```

I'm using a GPON SFP, and here are the specs for it;
[image: GPON SFP Specs]

[Direct link to GPON SFP if anyone wants more information from PDF spec sheet.](https://ecin.ca/gpon-stick-module-sfp-transceiver-with-a-built-in-gpon-onu-class-b/)

I also seem to have a healthy optical signal;

```
Physical interface: ge-0/0/7
    Laser bias current                        :  14.534 mA
    Laser output power                        :  0.7400 mW / -1.31 dBm
    Module temperature                        :  69 degrees C / 156 degrees F
    Module voltage                            :  3.2630 V
    Laser receiver power                      :  0.0145 mW / -18.39 dBm
    Laser bias current high alarm             :  Off
    Laser bias current low alarm              :  Off
    Laser bias current high warning           :  Off
    Laser bias current low warning            :  Off
    Laser output power high alarm             :  Off
    Laser output power low alarm              :  Off
    Laser output power high warning           :  Off
    Laser output power low warning            :  Off
    Module temperature high alarm             :  Off
    Module temperature low alarm              :  Off
    Module temperature high warning           :  Off
    Module temperature low warning            :  Off
    Module voltage high alarm                 :  Off
    Module voltage low alarm                  :  Off
    Module voltage high warning               :  Off
    Module voltage low warning                :  Off
    Laser rx power high alarm                 :  Off
    Laser rx power low alarm                  :  Off
    Laser rx power high warning               :  Off
    Laser rx power low warning                :  Off
    Laser bias current high alarm threshold   :  60.000 mA
    Laser bias current low alarm threshold    :  0.000 mA
    Laser bias current high warning threshold :  50.000 mA
    Laser bias current low warning threshold  :  0.000 mA
    Laser output power high alarm threshold   :  3.9810 mW / 6.00 dBm
    Laser output power low alarm threshold    :  0.8910 mW / -0.50 dBm
    Laser output power high warning threshold :  3.1620 mW / 5.00 dBm
    Laser output power low warning threshold  :  1.1220 mW / 0.50 dBm
    Module temperature high alarm threshold   :  95 degrees C / 203 degrees F
    Module temperature low alarm threshold    :  -50 degrees C / -58 degrees F
    Module temperature high warning threshold :  90 degrees C / 194 degrees F
    Module temperature low warning threshold  :  -45 degrees C / -49 degrees F
    Module voltage high alarm threshold       :  3.600 V
    Module voltage low alarm threshold        :  3.000 V
    Module voltage high warning threshold     :  3.500 V
    Module voltage low warning threshold      :  3.100 V
    Laser rx power high alarm threshold       :  0.2512 mW / -6.00 dBm
    Laser rx power low alarm threshold        :  0.0013 mW / -28.86 dBm
    Laser rx power high warning threshold     :  0.1995 mW / -7.00 dBm
    Laser rx power low warning threshold      :  0.0016 mW / -27.96 dBm
```

Hoping there are some Juniper or Lumen engineers lurking out there that may help me shed some light on why I haven't been able to successfully get Quantum up and running on my SRX320 :) Appreciate anyone's help/suggestions, thanks!

EDIT: This being an SRX, I should have included my security configurations also;

My Internet zone which contains my fiber uplink interface;

```
security-zone Internet {
    interfaces {
        ge-0/0/7.201 {
            host-inbound-traffic {
                system-services {
                    ping;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My firewall rule for Internet zone;

```
from-zone Internet to-zone Internet {
    policy Internet {
        match {
            source-address any;
            destination-address any;
            application any;
        }
        then {
            permit;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: My current interface/zone configs based on feedback below;

```
[edit interfaces ge-0/0/7]
eschin@Gandalf# show
vlan-tagging;
speed 1g;
gigether-options {
    no-auto-negotiation;
}
unit 201 {
    description "Quantum(centurylink) GPON fiber WAN.";
    vlan-id 201;
    family inet {
        dhcp {
            force-discover;
        }
    }
}
```

```
[edit security zones security-zone Internet]
eschin@Gandalf# show
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/7.201 {
        host-inbound-traffic {
            system-services {
                ping;
                dhcp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, still no DHCP being pulled.

EDIT:
Traffic diagnostic results (Left this running for about 20 minutes);

```
monitor traffic interface ge-0/0/7.201 size 334
verbose output suppressed, use <detail> or <extensive> for full protocol decode
Address resolution is ON. Use <no-resolve> to avoid any reverse lookup delay.
Address resolution timeout is 4s.
Listening on ge-0/0/7.201, capture size 334 bytes

Reverse lookup for 0.0.0.0 failed (check DNS reachability).
Other reverse lookup failures will not be reported.
Use <no-resolve> to avoid reverse lookups on IP addresses.

15:09:21.217183 Out IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 64:c3:d6:c0:a0:07, length 260
15:09:37.218619 Out IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 64:c3:d6:c0:a0:07, length 260
15:10:09.220803 Out IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 64:c3:d6:c0:a0:07, length 260
^C
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

```
show dhcp client statistics
Packets dropped:
    Total                      2
    Send error                 2

Messages received:
    BOOTREPLY                  0
    DHCPOFFER                  0
    DHCPACK                    0
    DHCPNAK                    0
    DHCPFORCERENEW             0

Messages sent:
    BOOTREQUEST                36
    DHCPDECLINE                0
    DHCPDISCOVER               36
    DHCPREQUEST                0
    DHCPINFORM                 0
    DHCPRELEASE                0
    DHCPRENEW                  0
    DHCPREBIND                 0
```

Comment: Is this an SFP ONT you purchased or one they provided? GPON requires ISP provisioning. Just because it sees light doesn't mean it's authorized to pass traffic.

Comment: It is an SFP ONT I purchased myself. From what searching I've done online, and Lumen's tech support, I 'should' be able to use my own equipment (provided the hardware is compatible and it's configured correctly.

The SFP ONT I purchased is a 'hardware match' to the one provided by Centurylink, which is this one; https://www.axon-networks.com/products/gpon-ont

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that jump out at me - first the encapsulation-type - not sure why this is set to dix, but I don't believe it is required.

Secondly, it doesn't look like you have dhcp enabled on your Internet security zone.  You should be able to fix both of these as follows:

```
delete interfaces ge-0/0/7 unit 0 encapsulation dix
set security zones security-zone Internet interface ge-0/0/7.0 host-inbound-traffic dhcp
```

Also, on routed interfaces, it's generally good practice to use a logical unit that matches the VLAN tag you're sending, so rather than using unit 0, use unit 201, but there will be some downstream impact if you change this (eg: you'll need to update all references in security zones and elsewhere).

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for the input.

I added my security configurations in response to your post. I'll try adding DHCP on inbound hosted services, but I thought that was just for services the router itself would be hosting, not for services it was acting as a client for.

Also, I added dix encapsulation due to this wiki/rfc;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPoE
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc894

And per the junos CLI help;
dix-Ethernet DIXv2 (RFC 894)

Though, adding the dix was after a more basic configuration did not work. Was 'grasping at straws' here. I'll try removing.

Comment: I'd intended to fix the logical unit numbering. I wasn't paying attention to that when I initially setup the config. Thought about it afterwards (: It was bugging me too, haha

Comment: Updated my original post with current configs based on suggestions, but unfortunately, still no DHCP address getting pulled.

Comment: IPoE in the ISP sense really just means that your link is running over native ethernet rather than being encapsulated in PPP first, which is why DHCP is required rather than PPPoE address negotiation, so the encapsulation should not be required.  As for your issue, try using "monitor traffic interface ge-0/0/7.0 layer2-headers" to confirm your DHCP requests are going out and if any Offers are coming back and are correctly tagged.  Also, look at the output of "show dhcp client statistics" to see if there are any errors being received.

Comment: That was my understanding of IPoE as well, so good to know I'm not 'barking up the wrong tree' :)

I included the diagnostics you suggested in my original post. Looks like what I've suspected... My equipment is sending out requests, but absolutely nothing coming back. It does seem like upstream/ISP is not talking back to my equipment for some reason.

Hard to get good information from tier 1 tech support... I do worry they're using something upstream to block unauth'd gear, even though I've been assured it 'should' work.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just putting the provided C5500XK into transparent bridging mode, and I was successfully able to pull an IP with basic IPoE configurations on the Juniper router.

I suspect the original issue was a hardware incompatibility I couldn't get to the bottom of. Juniper hardware has a bit of a reputation of 'not playing nice' with third party SFPs.... Or the SFP itself was a bit FUBAR, even though it's hardware specs were a spot-on match with the C5500XK.

I'd like to eventually remove the C5500XK from the chain altogether, but I will revisit the hardware specifics at a later date. It at least appears to be working with transparent bridging option :)